# Parameters through XML

Tags: asp.net, xml

Here's the piece of XML

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tb1" Text="0" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="tb2" Text="0" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br /> 
<a href="Handler.aspx?a="TEXT FROM tb1" & b="TEXT FROM tb2">handler</a>
```

and now a question - how can I bind tb1.Text with parameter 'a' and tb2.Text with parameter 'b' through XML?
Thanks.

Comment: Please, explain what do you mean in "through XML"? Probably, you need to use JQuery and on document.ready set the values of textboxes?

Comment: If you mean that on a web page, you want to alter an URL to replace certain variables with input from textboxes on that page, you're going to need JavaScript.

Comment: isn't it possible through such constructions - <% blablabla %> ?

Comment: No, `<% blablabla %>` runs serverside. So if you want that, you're going to need a postback.

Comment: I thought such a thing would work a=<%tb1.Text%> but it doesn't:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="callHandler">handler</a>
...
<script language="JavaScript">
    function callHandler() { 
      window.location.href = "Handler.aspx?a=" 
                           + document.getElementById("tb1").getAttribute("Text") 
                           + "&b=" 
                           + document.getElementById("tb2").getAttribute("Text");
    }
</script>
```